# Using Visual Studio MEF Extension to add error messages for external files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, mef

I've been looking through the MEF [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx), but just can't seem to solve this one.

I'm currently trying to convert an Managed Package Framework Language Service entirely to MEF. I see how the Error Squiggles ([IErrorTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.ierrortag.aspx)) work for the current file, but my parser generates error messages for included files (some of which may not be open in the editor) and sometimes additional parser messages that do not relate to a span of code as well.

Is there any way to add messages directly to the "Error List" from Managed Extensibility Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this is probably something that isn't exposed in VS through MEF.  You'll probably need to use a legacy way of adding error messages, such as through the DTE object model.